# Convert Selected row to JSON - PHP

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

I want to convert selected result into JSON.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
include("DbConnect.php");
    $connection=new DbConnect();
$sth = mysqli_query($connection->_con,"SELECT * FROM account WHERE ac_id='1'");
                if($sth){
                $rows = array();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)){
                  $users = mysqli_query($connection->_con,"SELECT user.user_id,user.name,user.email,ac_detail.ac_id,ac_detail.amount FROM user,ac_detail WHERE ac_detail.ac_id='1' AND user.user_id=ac_detail.user_id");
                  $usersArray = array();
                  while($userRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)){
                   $usersArray[]=$userRow;
                  }
                  $a=array("users"=>$usersArray);
                  //$row["user"]=$usersArray
                    array_push($row,$a);
                  $rows[] = $row; 
                }
                echo json_encode(array('data'=>$rows));
                }else{
                  echo json_encode(array('message'=>'error - 2'));
                }

?>
```

By executing this code it generate JSON like :

> `{"data":[{"ac_id":"1","user_id":"2","title":"Travel","ac_for":"Traveling","required_amount":"50","current_amount":"0","initial_date":"2014-11-11","final_date":"2014-11-14","is_shared":"1","status":"1","0":{"users":[{"user_id":"2","name":"Muhammad Imran","email":"macrotechnolgies@gmail.com","ac_id":"1","amount":"0"},{"user_id":"3","name":"Muhammad Imran","email":"macrotecholgies@gmail.com","ac_id":"1","amount":"0"}]}}]}`

But i don't want "0"{"user::...}

How it should be (Expected Results) :

> `{"data":[{"ac_id":"1","user_id":"2","title":"Travel","ac_for":"Traveling","required_amount":"50","current_amount":"0","initial_date":"2014-11-11","final_date":"2014-11-14","is_shared":"1","status":"1","users":[{"user_id":"2","name":"Muhammad Imran","email":"macrotechnolgies@gmail.com","ac_id":"1","amount":"0"},{"user_id":"3","name":"Muhammad Imran","email":"macrotecholgies@gmail.com","ac_id":"1","amount":"0"}]}]}`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're doing:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)){
    [...snip...]
    array_push($row,$a);
```

The `while` line creates an array `$row`, which you then use parts of to create `$a`. You then push that `$a` BACK onto the original `$row` array. But `$row` is an associative array already, so the pushed `$a` gets key 0.

Since you're now mixing an associative array (non-numeric keys) with a numeric-keyed array (the push operation), PHP **MUST** add the numeric key to your pushed item: You can't have an element in an array WITHOUT a key.

Then, since JS doesn't allow actual JS arrays (`[]`) to have non-numeric keys, the whole thing has to get converted into an object (`{}`).

What you probably want is something more like:

```
while($row = ...) {
    ... build $a ...
    array_push($row['users'], $a);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you in stead `array_push($row,$a)` try following:

```
<?php
include("DbConnect.php");
$connection=new DbConnect();

$sth = mysqli_query($connection->_con,"SELECT * FROM account WHERE ac_id='1'");

if($sth){
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)){

    $users = mysqli_query($connection->_con,"SELECT user.user_id,  user.name, user.email, ac_detail.ac_id, ac_detail.amount FROM user,ac_detail WHERE ac_detail.ac_id='1' AND user.user_id=ac_detail.user_id");
    $usersArray = array();

    while($userRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)){
         $usersArray[]=$userRow;
    }

// here comes the change
  //  $a = array("users"=>$usersArray);
  //            //$row["user"]=$usersArray

  //  array_push($row,$a);

    $row['users'] = $usersArray;

    $rows[] = $row; 
}

echo json_encode(array('data'=>$rows));

}else{

  echo json_encode(array('message'=>'error - 2'));

}
```

This should work. Dont have sample data to test it.

Comment: you should leave the answer so anyone with similar problem and check the answer here as correct if lead you to figure out the solution....